# sed: search and replace values at position for last line of file

Tags: bash, sed

I have a fixed width file where the **last line** of the file needs to be checked at a certain **position**, and if value is found at that position, it is changed to another value specified by an **ARRAY**.  The input file looks like this for the last line

`210204154828000999990000056000000072328100000540000000`

The values of interest are at position 27, 40 and 47.  The values at those positions are 6, 1, 4 respectively.  I'm using an ARRAY for checking these values.  If the position of the ARRAY matches the value of the position, replace with the value of the ARRAY location.  The code looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash

chars=( { A B C D E F G H I )

for num in "${!chars[@]}" 
do  
    sed -i -E '$ s%^(.{26})$num%\1${chars[$num]}%' $1
done
```

I don't get a failure when running this but I don't see it updating the last line either.  The expected output if this were working correctly would be the following:

`21020415482800099999000005F000000072328A000005D0000000`

The command to execute is as follows

`# ./convert.sh file1.txt`

I'm sure something is wrong with my sed but I just can't figure it out.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The "C" should be a "D", right?

Comment: Yes the correct output looks like this `21020513372400099999000005F000000072328A000005D0000000  `  I will update the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in [xhienne's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66054970/6770384), your command did not work since `$num` and `${chars[$num]}` were written inside single quotes `'...'` where bash does no expansion of variables. Use double quotes `"..."` instead.

In this answer, I just want to point out a trick to make the script more efficient. Right now you do `sed -i` ten times. That is, the file has to be read over and over again. You can do everything in a single `sed` command whose command string is dynamically generated:

```
#!/bin/bash

chars=( '{' {A..I} )
cmd=()
for num in "${!chars[@]}"; do
  for pos in 27 40 47; do
    cmd+=(-e "\$ s%^(.{$((pos-1))})$num%\\1${chars[num]}%")
  done
done
sed -Ei "${cmd[@]}" "$1"
```

Like your original script, this only works if `chars` is free of `sed` control characters like `\`, `%`, and `&`. If you need one of these chars escape them manually as in `chars=('\\' '\%' '\&')` or automatically with another sed command.

Comment: That only changes the character at position 27 of the input, it doesn't update the ones at positions 40 and 47 too, you'd need another loop to cycle through all the char positions to change. It'd also fail in various ways if we had `chars=( '{' A B C D E '&' G H I )` or `chars=( '{' A B C D E '%' G H I )` or various other characters in the replacements list.

Comment: Oh right, thank you for the feedback. I already mentioned the problems with the chars `\`, `%`, and `&` and don't think this is a problem for OP. However, I totally overlooked the other positions as OP didn't include them in their script. I fixed it.

Comment: @Socowi I think the positions you use are off by 1.  `for pos in 27 40 47;` should be `for pos in 26 39 46;` and that seems to work for me

Comment: The only chars used for sub here are `{ A B C D E F G H I } J K L M N O P Q R`.  The last 10 are not needed in this as the numbers here will never be negative which are being replaced.

Comment: @Gene Yes, the positions were off by 1. Thank you for the notice. I fixed it by using `$((pos-1))` for readability of `for pos in ...`.

Comment: This answer was able to complete what I needed based on the question asked.  I will say I will be reviewing some of the other solutions to see if I can replace my current code with a better solution that uses less effort from the system.  Thanks to all that contributed and assistance with this.  It has been very helpful

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to have to process the file 10 times for each index.

Here's a single call to awk

```sh
tac file | awk '
    BEGIN {
        split("A B C D E F G H I", chars); chars[0] = "{"
        split("27 40 47", idx)
    }
    FNR == 1 {
        line = $0
        for (i in idx) {
            char = substr(line, idx[i], 1)
            repl = chars[char]
            line = substr(line, 1, idx[i]-1) repl substr(line, idx[i]+1)
        }
        $0 = line
    }
    1
' | tac
```

That reverses the file, operates on the first line, then re-reverses the file

---

To save inplace, use `sponge` from the moreutils package:

```sh
tac file | awk '...' | tac | sponge file
```

or use a temp file

```sh
tmp=$(mktemp)
tac file | awk '...' | tac > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" file
```

---

The equivalent perl is unsurprisingly more concise

```sh
tac file | perl -pe '
    BEGIN { @c = qw/ { A B C D E F G H I /; }
    $. == 1 or next;
    s/{^(.{26})(\d)(.{12})(\d)(.{6})(\d)/$1$c[$2]$3$c[$4]$5$c[$6]/;
' | ...
```

Somewhat more readable:

```sh
tac file | perl -pe '
    BEGIN { @c = qw/ { A B C D E F G H I /; }
    $. == 1 or next;
    s{^(.{26}) (\d)    (.{12}) (\d)   (.{6}) (\d)   }
     {   $1  . $c[$2]  . $3  . $c[$4] . $5 . $c[$6] }xe;
' | ...
```

Comment: This seems so much more complicated. Isn't `tac` very expensive? If so, `head -n-1 file; tail -n1 file | yourCommand` could be better. However, I would stick to `sed` with a dynamically generated command: `cmd=(); for ...; do cmd+=(-e "\$ s%^..."); done; sed -Ei "${cmd[@]}" "$1"`.

Comment: Many good ideas. I'd encourage you to contribute an answer. You'll get my vote.

Comment: @Socowi I'd also be interested in seeing a complete solution using that approach of generating a sed command. It's worth pointing out that Glenns awk script will work for any replacement chars, not just alphabetic ones while a sed script would have to special-case script delimiters, `&`, backslashes if the subsequent char was a number, , etc.

Comment: @glennjackman when you say "the equivalent perl" it's not **really** the equivalent perl as it's using hard-coded calculated character positions and would require significant changes if the OP wanted to add a 4th character position, say, unlike the awk script. idk how robust it'd be to various other chars in the replacement list. You could write the **equivalent** code in GNU awk with `match($0,/.../,a){$0=a[1] ... c[a[26]] ...}`

Comment: FWIW I posted an awk equivalent of those perl scripts at the end of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66056600/1745001). I also got hold of a computer that had perl to test with and the first perl script didn't change the input, it just printed it as-is, but the second one worked. I don't know perl well enough to guess at why.

Answer (score 3):

You program would be ok if your bash variables were substituted in your `sed` command, but the use of single quotes prevents this.

Use double quotes around your shell variables:

```
sed -i -E '$ s%^(.{26})'"$num"'%\1'"${chars[$num]}%"
```

Comment: I think you missed a ' or ".  I used the following and it did work for my example. `sed -i -E '$ s%^(.{26})'"$num"'%\1'"${chars[$num]}"'%' $1`

Comment: The last `%` doesn't need to be quoted, if this is what you mean, but it doesn't hurt to quote it. It can even be moved inside the double quotes that precede it. Answer updated anyway.

Comment: That only changes the character at position 27 of the input, it doesn't update the ones at positions 40 and 47 too, you'd need a loop to cycle through all the char positions to change. It'd also fail in various ways if we had `chars=( '{' A B C D E '&' G H I )` or `chars=( '{' A B C D E '%' G H I )` or various other characters in the replacements list.

Comment: @EdMorton The original question is not about how to make 26 a variable. It is "why my sed command fails to update the last line".

Comment: No it's not, its about `The values of interest are at position 27, 40 and 47` and `The expected output if this were working correctly would be the following: 21020415482800099999000005F000000072328A000005C0000000` with all 3 positions changed. The OP is clearly asking for help creating a script that'll change characters at multiple positions.

Comment: @EdMorton You are free to believe that OP's code doesn't work because Gene forgot to repeat the same command for character positions 40 and 47. I prefer to think that he is smarter than that and that he just doesn't understand how shell variable substitution works.

Comment: If the OP repeated that line 2 more times then they would have 3 lines of code that would fail given various characters in the replacement list, would be opening/closing/overwriting the input file 3 times, and would have to write more (or modify) hard-coded lines every time they want to add/change a character position so correcting that one part of the implementation of that line isn't the best way to help the OP with what they are really trying to do - replace multiple characters at multiple positions of a string.

Comment: I have a similar piece of code working in another part of my script that iterates over the entire file for a single position.  This code is inefficient for sure.  The problem I was having was the use of the quotes, single or double.  Learning better ways to do things is why I come to this place though.  For that, both of you are correct.  xhienne gave me what I needed to correct the single position.  Ed and others have me learning a better way to do my task which will have me reviewing the rest of my code for better efficiency. Making my code more efficient was not my OP but appreciated.

Comment: @Gene you should also take into account that, in addition to being more efficient, the awk scripts posted are more robust, more portable, and easier to enhance/maintain than a shell loop calling sed. You might also be interested in reading [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) if you're considering using shell loops to process text in future - it doesn't all directly apply in this case but the fundamental issues do.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for that read. At the ripe age of 85 and still learning new stuff is important.  The key here for me is creating automation.  This file will be retrieved daily and the script will be executed by cron then pushed nightly to a receiving SFTP server for processing the conversion to of course....AS400.  Something that I can relate to in age ;)

Answer (score 3):

Your input file needs to be 2 or more lines to test that only the last line changes, so lets start with this sample input:

```
$ cat file
210204154828000999990000056000000072328100000540000000
210204154828000999990000056000000072328100000540000000
```

and then given this script:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR > 1 { print prev }
{ prev = $0 }
END {
    split("A B C D E F G H I",chars); chars[0]="{"
    split("27 40 47",poss)
    for (i in poss) {
        pos = poss[i]
        charIdx = substr(prev,pos,1)
        prev = substr(prev,1,pos-1) chars[charIdx] substr(prev,pos+1)
    }
    print prev
}
```

We get this output:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
210204154828000999990000056000000072328100000540000000
21020415482800099999000005F000000072328A000005D0000000
```

---

EDIT: FWIW here is the gawk equivalent of the perl script at the end of [@GlennJackman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66054792/1745001):

```
$ tac file |
    awk 'BEGIN { split("A B C D E F G H I",c); c[0]="}" }
    NR==1 && match($0,/^(.{26})([0-9])(.{12})([0-9])(.{6})([0-9])(.*)/,a) {
        $0 = a[1] c[a[2]] a[3] c[a[4]] a[5] c[a[6]] a[7]
    } 1' | tac
210204154828000999990000056000000072328100000540000000
21020415482800099999000005F000000072328A000005D0000000
```

Comment: Yes, the input file last line is what I posted.  The rest of the file is of no context but several hundred lines.  Since the focus was on the last line, I only provided the last line sample. Thanks for this code snippet.  I didn't think of AWK for this instance but will review for fit since it appears much more efficient

Comment: @Gene it's a common mistake to only post the text you want modified in your question but unfortunately while it's usually easy to write a script to modify the text you want, it's often much harder to write that script such that it doesn't modify text you do **not** want modified and so you should always include both in your sample input/output which in your case would mean adding a line or 2 before the last one.

Comment: The awk script I posted is not just much more efficient than a shell loop calling sed its also much more robust as it'll work for any chars in your replacement list, unlike any of the sed solutions posted so far and much more portable as it'll work using any awk in any shell on every Unix box, again unlike any of the sed scripts posted so far, and easier to enhance to target more/less/different character positions in future (or do anything else) than any of the sed scripts posted so far.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `sed` inside a loop is inefficient. Below is a `bash` script calling
`sed` once to do the job without using any other external command (tested with GNU `sed`).

```
#!/bin/bash

digit='0123456789'
chars='{ABCDEFGHI'

# The below two assignments are not necessary if chars cannot contain
# the '\' and '/' characters
chars=${chars//\\/\\\\}
chars=${chars//\//\\\/}

first=27  # first position
middle=40 # middle position
last=47   # last position
f=$((first-1))        # number of characters before the first position
m=$((middle-first-1)) # number of characters between middle and first positions
l=$((last-middle-1))  # number of characters between last and middle positions

sed -i -E "
$ {
    h
    s/.{$f}(.).{$m}(.).{$l}(.).*/\1\2\3/
    y/$digit/$chars/
    G
    s/(.)(.)(.).(.{$f}).(.{$m}).(.{$l})./\4\1\5\2\6\3/
}
" "$1"
```

Comment: Impressive. I imagine the `{` char is intended to map to `0`

Comment: That would fail if we had `chars="ABCDE/GHI"` or similar. It's also hard-coding 3 specific character positions which is probably undesirable as it'd take a rewrite if you also wanted to change, say, the 12th character position (i.e. change less than or more than 3 char positions).

Comment: @EdMorton The first issue could be solved by escaping backslashes and slashes inside the `chars` before calling sed: `chars=${chars//\\/\\\\}` and `chars=${chars//\//\\\/}`, in that order. For the second issue, it is not much difficult to write a `bash` script generating a `sed` script for a variable number of positions.

Comment: If such a shell script could be written to efficiently, robustly portably (or even bash-only), easily maintainably produce efficient, robust,sed code that works for all characters using a POSIX sed so it's portable across Unix boxes then it'd be worth looking at to see if it has any advantages over an equivalent awk script. If it can't then there's just no point even going through the exercise of trying when it's trivial to do the whole job efficiently, robustly, portably and easily maintainably directly in POSIX awk.

Comment: Best I can tell any time you're considering writing a shell script to generate sed scripts you'd be better of simply writing an awk script to do the whole job instead but that's just based on what I've seen over my 40+ years of shell programming (I don't mean that to sound facetious, it just is what it is), maybe there's some case I haven't seen where it's useful, idk.

Comment: @EdMorton All of those are true, but not directly relevant to the question. The question is tagged with `sed`, which is also specifically mentioned in the title of the question, and the question doesn't contain an `awk` tag.

Comment: People regularly tag questions with the Unix tool(s) they think might be right and then accept answers using whichever tool provides the right solution. That's why the people listed as the top answerers of sed questions (see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sed/topusers) aren't necessarily the ones posting the most sed answers but instead just the ones most often helping people who think they might need to use sed come up with the best solution for them.

Comment: Where are we mapping { to 0?  Am I missing something in this answer?

Comment: @EdMorton I don't object at all to the better solutions using alternative tools not specified in the question, but my primary preference is giving answers constrained to the tags and specifications described in the question.

Comment: @Gene I first thought it was unintentional but it seems `0` is really intended to be replaced with `{`. I updated the answer to reflect this intention and also added a check for two characters special to `sed`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a straight `sed` version, changing positions 27, 40, and 47 of last line using a lookup table temporarily inserted at end of line; assuming those positions - and none of their replacements - are digits 0-9 only.

```sed
sed -E -e '
$!b
s/$/\n1A2B3C4D5E6F7G8H9I0{/
s/^(.{26})(.)(.[^\n]*)(\n.*\2(.).*)/\1\5\3\4/
s/^(.{39})(.)(.[^\n]*)(\n.*\2(.).*)/\1\5\3\4/
s/^(.{46})(.)(.[^\n]*)(\n.*\2(.).*)/\1\5\3/
' -- file
```

**EDIT**

Some additional explanations, as per comments:

- `$!b` : unless on last line skip to next line
- `s/$/\n1A2B3C4D5E6F7G8H9I0{/` : append a newline followed by a lookup table to the end of line, interleaving lookups (digits `0-9`) and their replacements (`A-{`)
- the 3 `s` commands use grouping `(…)`, multiple-character matching `{…}`, and back references `\1` thru `\5`, to produce the desired output
- each `s` captures the characters before position N as `\1`, char. at pos. N as `\2`, chars after pos. N up to newline as `\3`, lookup table as `\4`, and replacement as `\5`; using `\2` to determine the lookup
- last `s` strips the lookup table (no `\4`)

The `-e` option is often omitted before a short script string but I tend to use it when also using `--` to mark the end of options. `-E` is a GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) option to enable extended regular expressions [ERE](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04) - over the default basic ditto [BRE](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03). In this case ERE improves readability: you can use BRE here but then you'd have to escape all `(){}` - except those in the replacement sections of `s` commands.

The GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed)-specific `-i` option (inline editing) can be convenient but AFAIK is slower than `cmd -- file1 > file2 && mv -f -- file2 file1`.

As for the italics in the code block: they have no special meaning here, I tried to get rid of them but SO's markdown engine isn't 100% compatble with the one I'm using (has to do with the `*`'s). [editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) says 'Markdown and HTML are ignored within a code block' but not wanting to make an escaping error I let it ride.

Comment: Nice! Maybe explaining how exactly this works would be welcome by the OP. It's worth noting that this solution is valid as long as you don't map digits to digits (this is not required by the OP, and you don't have to assume this is, but the reader should be aware of the limitations of this solution). One thing that is missing in here: `{` should be mapped to '0' (see OP).

Comment: @xhienne: Hmm, I made room for the `0` to `{` substitution but didn't finish it... my answer is now updated.

Comment: A little color on this would be great to understand what's happening here.  I've never used both -E and -e with sed.  Usually use -i for inplace.  Not sure why part of the answer is in italics.  Is there specific attention needed there?

Comment: @Gene: Fair enough, I elaborated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

With `perl` how about:

```
perl -pe '
    if (eof) {
        for $i (27, 40, 47) {
            substr($_, $i - 1, 1) = (qw/ { A B C D E F G H I /)[substr($_, $i - 1, 1)];
        }
    }
' file
```

The `substr()` function can also be used as an l-value to be assigned.

Answer (score 0):

```
{mawk/mawk2/gawk} -v VALMAPPING='27|6|40|1|47|4' 'BEGIN {

       RS = "^$"; ORS = FS = OFS = "\n";
       nx = split(VALMAPPING, arrMap, "|"); 

       for (x = 1; x < nx; x += 2) { src[arrMap[x]] = arrMap[x+1]; };

    } END { if ($(NF)=="") { NF--; };

       for (x=1; x < NF; x++) { print $(x) };
       FS = OFS = ""; $0 = $(NF);

       for (x in src) { 
          if (($(x) ~ /[0-9]/) && ($(src[x]) ~ /[0-9]/)) { $(x) = $(src[x]) }
       }; 

       print }'
```

I presume you wanted the rows other than the last to be directly printed without being checked. so that's the first for( ) loop in the END section. Once done with that, change the FS to blank string to so every digit becomes its own field. Then replacements occur only when it exists.

Trade off is doing 3 for loops. Gain is no substr( ) gsub( ) or match( ) needed.